# Create Intellisense inside a Word Add-in

Tags: ms-word, intellisense

I have an add-in in MSWord.  One of the ways in which users interact with it requires a user to type into a Word document "commands" and also their own user-defined "data elements".  I would like to provide the user with some Intellisense to help them type these commands and data elements.  Has anyone done anything like that (I guess it involves trapping user key-strokes destined for Word and to do something with them before handing the key-stroke on to Word, but it would be nice if someone had found an easier way).  Oh, yes, I program in C#.

Comment: Hi did you ever get anywhere with this? Love to know if you did.

Comment: I haven't done anything on this for a while.  But I remember reading somewhere that someone else had tried to do something on it using VBA's "Range" rather than "Selection".  Apparently "Selection" sort of refers to the point in the Word document just to the right of the cursor (mostly), whereas "Range" refers to what the user has just typed - i.e. to the left of the cursor.  One day when I've got nothing else to do :) I will look into it again.